# mysql merge the same data and keep the updated one later

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `goods` (
  `id` int NOT NULL ,
  `name` varchar(25) ,
  `updateat` datetime 
)
```

Now there is a piece of data like this in the table

[image]

When I want to insert a new piece of data like `(1,'new','2021-12-18 12:00:00')`.First determine whether there is the same data in the table as the data to be inserted (except for the update time),Then compare the update time, keep the latest piece of data.

I want to know how to use sql to achieve this function.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: i use mysql.....

Comment: Can you explain *the same data* ? Do you mean only changing `updateat` value for the same upcoming `id` and `name` pair ?(eg deleting the existing and inserting the new)

Comment: Yes, that's what i means

Answer (score 3):

First add primary key to your table:

```
CREATE TABLE goods (
  id int NOT NULL ,
  name varchar(25) ,
  updateat datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
)
```

Then use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` :

```
insert into goods values (1, 'john', '2021-01-02');
insert into goods (id, name, updateat)
 values (1, 'john', '2021-01-03')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
 updateat = greatest('2021-01-03', 
                     (select updateat from (select * from goods as g) as g where id = 1))
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01dab6d2cc908448817d186247b2fb39)

Comment: thank you very much,is there a way to not add a primary key？Because I need to ensure that the structure of the table is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql uses [INSERT ON...DUPLICATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead of merge. This statement allows you to make modifications in your case an update based on a check when duplicate entries are identified. Duplicate entries may be identified using primary keys or unique indexes. The demo below and working db fiddle gives an example of this based on your criteria.

1. Using a unique index to identify duplicate entries
2. Using `INSERT ON...DUPLICATE` with the `VALUES` (used to identify currently inserted values) and a case expression to determine which `updatedat` date is more recent.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `goods` (
>   `id` int NOT NULL ,
>   `name` varchar(25) ,
>   `updateat` datetime 
> );
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- use a unique index if you are interested in ensuring a subset of columns are unique and 
> -- these columns do not meet the criteria to be a primary/composite key based on your database design
> create unique index uk_id_name on  goods(id,name);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into goods values (1,'new','2021-12-18 12:00:00');
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- this should fail because of the duplicate unique index
> insert into goods values (1,'new','2021-12-18 12:00:00');
> ```
>
> ```
> Duplicate entry '1-new' for key 'uk_id_name'
> ```

> ```
> select * from goods;
> ```

> ```
> id | name | updateat           
> -: | :--- | :------------------
>  1 | new  | 2021-12-18 12:00:00
> ```

> ```
> insert into goods values (1,'new','2021-12-18 12:00:01')
> on duplicate key update updateat= CASE 
>    WHEN updateat > VALUES(updateat) THEN updateat
>    ELSE VALUES(updateat)
> END;
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from goods;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | updateat           
> -: | :--- | :------------------
>  1 | new  | 2021-12-18 12:00:01
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d35dee210db80c003eb1fb778430f1ed)*